# Return de um AJAX não está voltando valor na Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, funções

Tenho um função que executa um AJAX, a resposta do AJAX eu retorno no 'return', porem quando dou um console.log no returno da função não me volta nenhum dado.
Abaixo está o código.

```
function getListEmployee() {
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open("GET", 'http://localhost/erp/api/v1/employee.php');

ajax.responseType = "json";

ajax.send();
ajax.addEventListener("readystatechange" , function () {
    if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){
        var response = ajax.response;
        return response;
    }
})
}

const data = getListEmployee()
```

Answer (score 0):

A classe `XMLHttpRequest` tem um comportamento assíncrono, se você colocar alguns `console.log`, vai ver que eles são exibidos em uma ordem diferente, isso ajuda a compreender como é o fluxo.

Normalmente quando vamos consumir um API em Javascript, utilizamos de `Promises` (`async/await`).

Veja o seu exemplo, retornando uma `Promise` e sendo consumido com `then` e também com `await`:

```js
function getListEmployee() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.open("GET", "https://putsreq.com/YYHUDSjLxodiUUhdnP0K");

    ajax.onload = function() {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(ajax.response);
      } else {
        reject(ajax.statusText);
      }
    };

    ajax.onerror = function() {
      reject(ajax.statusText);
    };

    ajax.send();
  });
}

//Com await
(async () => {
  const data = await getListEmployee();
  console.log("Com async", data);
})();

//Resolvendo a promise
getListEmployee()
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Com then", response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Veja que agora, a função `getListEmployee` retorna um `Promise` e quando a API é consumida com sucesso, resolvemos a `Promise`, caso contrário, rejeitamos a mesma.

O consumo pode ser feito com `await`, que existe estar dentro de uma função assíncrona (`async`) ou resolvendo a `Promise` com then/catch.

---

> Documentações:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Mesmo colocando  desta forma que passou, não consigo acessar o valor diretamente, pois preciso usar o resultado em outra função.

Comment: É bem capaz que você tenha de refatorar parte do seu código, para que a função que venha a consumir a getListEmployee passe a ser uma função assíncrona e possa então usar await.